# Render water-paint in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es, glsl

I have been working with `OpenGL` in iOS, and setting the colors with `glColor4f(r,g,b,a)` and then drawing my own color on a white `UIImageView`. I basically have a brush, which is then moved around my user's touch, and then it paints the color onto the canvas. But this color needs to be water paint (like smudged color)

Does anyone understand/knows how to get a water color like this app does, and how the background `UIImageView` has a texture on it?

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hello-watercolor/id539414526?mt=8

or checkout water paint in this. http://www.fiftythree.com/paper

I created a bounty on this as I am really having a hard time to grasp how to derive such smooth flowing colors out of the normal colors. Even if you guys point me in the right direction, or to some sample code on how I can get the effect of `water-paint`, it would be really helpful ^_^

And as a bonus, it would be also be helpful if you can point out to me how to get canvas on which it is painted on looks realistic, and blended with the paint? Does `Blending/GLSL` have to do with any of this?

Is there any sample project on this?

Comment: I know at least one such application that does this by computing a simulation of how fluid flows on dry paper, based on a specific solution from this publication: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.2368 . Andy Finnell gave a presentation on how to do this using OpenCL at NSConference a few years ago: http://perspx.com/archives/nsconf-2010-mac-developer-conference-day-2/ , but I can't seem to find the video for that.

Comment: Can you post some code that you are working on ?

Comment: Sure, but its not what I am trying to achieve. Its just normal painting on canvas by setting a specific color.  This is the code I am working on - https://github.com/nskboy/glpaint

Answer (score 5):

If you are still struggling with the basics of getting realistic looking water colors working, you may want to experiment/prototype in photoshop first.

http://www.zoepiel.com/tutorials/watercolor/ shows some very effective tricks for creating watercolor images with simple tools.

The most interesting one is to multiply a group of watercolor layers with a greyscale watercolor paper image. The texture of the paper makes some parts remain white, and other parts saturate with color, just like real watercolor.

Each layer remains 'wet' in the sense that the colors within it blend, but the layers are 'dry' with respect to each other.

She also explains some of her brush and blur settings and shows what they do.

Once you can produce the desired effect in photoshop, you'll have clear specifications of what you want to do and you'll be quite a bit closer to programming it out.

Comment: How will being closer to an effect on photoshop be anywhere close to the actual code?

Comment: Have you seen the 5 video's on youtube? It's a surprisingly good effect, created from carefully tweaked simple settings. It is way easier to experiment with settings and tools in an environment where they have already been programmed out. Once you find settings that work, you can reproduce them in code. The multiplication of the texture image and the watercolor layers, for instance. Or the hardest one, the brush settings. They are simple enough to reproduce once you found out what you are looking for but it's important to first determine what you want the code to do.

Comment: I see your point. Your answer is more of a help in understanding the question, or points to the answer very indirectly. But this is not exactly the solution I expected.  I have a working solution after 2 weeks. lol. It has to do with GLSL shaders that I have written. I will post the code for it in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the examples you posted, it looks like they are using a simple Gaussian Blur with a radius of double your brush size. This may be an incomplete solution, but it's at least the first level.