# How to do Water color painting in iOS using CoreGraphics?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, drawing, core-graphics

I am working on Coloring App , in that i have to do coloring using water colors like that
[image: image i am attaching,] 
I have a brush, which is then moved around finger touch, and then it paints the color onto the imageview. But this color needs to be water paint (like image i posted)

Does anyone knows how to get a water color?

Is there any sample project related to water color in ios?

I also check this but didn't get successed [render-water-paint-in-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509722/render-water-paint-in-ios)

This is not duplicate i check all the link related to water coloring but didn't get what i want means i am working on coloring app in that i am drawing & filling colors(using flood fill alogrithm) on same imageView now i have to do painting using normal colors as well as water color but i haven't find any useful link.

Comment: @Amar i already tried this but didn't get how to achieve my task of water coloring.

Comment: @Sport This link shows how to draw using simple colors ? but not show water coloring effects.

Comment: This is non-photorealistic image processing domain. Try to see if there is any such library in Open CV.

Comment: @myCodeHurts  Can you give me some reference?

Comment: @Nilesh_iOSDev Hi, did you eventually find out anything on this? If so, please share your Knowledge or experience. Thanks in advance.